# Mistakenly installed incorrect version of linux-tools-common now unable to run apt install commands

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have kernel version 5.15.0-87-generic but mistakenly tried installing linux-tools-5.4.0-166 and linux-tools-5.4.0-166-generic. It failed and now whenever I try to install or remove any package, or uninstall linux-tools, I get:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However, that command results in the error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive 
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.4.0-166.183_all.deb
 (--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-5.15-tools-common 5.15.0-1043.49~20.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.4.0-166.183_all.deb
```

sudo apt remove for these packages results in the system asking me to run the `--fix-missing` command again.

Please help.